# SQL Selecting rows with same value of foreign key

Tags: sql, relational-database

Does anyone know how to select all rows from a table with same value of FK without giving its value ? I have a database with warehouse. It has sectors and items of certain values in each sector . I want to select the sectors where overall value of items bigger than a certain number with a single query . And i want the query to be universal - it should sum up overall values of items in every sector of the warehouse ( without specyfing number of secotrs or how many sectors are there ) Anyone knows how to do it ? I don't need a full query, just a way to say my database that it to sum up all values in certain sectors. SectorID is the Foreign Key and Item is the table ( with ItemID as public key and Value as value of item )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make use of a combination of queries. Basically, this problem can be solved as below:

Assuming the presence of ID columns in both the Item and Sector tables. Let the value that acts as the threshold **T** (a certain number returned by a single query as stated above):

1. Use an inner query to select sector.sectorid, Item.itemid and Item.value by joining the Sector and Item tables on the Item.SectorID = Sector.SectorID Where Item.value > **T**
2. Sum(Item.value) on the result obtained from the inner query above and GROUP BY(SECTORID), GROUPBY(ITEMID).

Comment: SELECT SectorID FROM Sector WHERE (
SELECT SUM(Value) FROM Item GROUP BY SectorID ) > 100;
Worked Just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want a `group by` query.  This is pretty basic, so I assume you are pretty new to SQL:

```
select SectorId, sum(itemValue) as TotalItemValue
from warehouse w 
group by SectorId
having sum(itemValue) > YOURVALUEHERE;
```

If you want the items in the sectors, then you can get that with a `join` or `in`:

```
select *
from warehouse w
where SectorId in (select SectorId
                   from warehouse
                   group by SectorId
                   having sum(itemValue) > YOURVALUEHERE
                  )
```